# Initialising number variables with null and checking for empty values

Tags: angular, typescript

I have to set a component property to null initially because I want an empty input when the page loads. I need to check if the string is empty but I can't do that when it is null, actually I can, everything still works from the user perspective but it throws an error so I suppose I shouldn't do it this way. So how can I check for an empty string with a nullable variable?

```
export class ExpensesLogComponent implements OnInit {
  inputHelperTextVisible: boolean = false;
  expenses: number = null;
```

Check if empty:

```
 onKey(event: any) {
    if (event.key === 'Enter') {
      console.log('enter pressed!');
    }
    // error is this.expenses = null
    if (this.expenses.toString() === '') {
      this.inputHelperTextVisible = false;
    } else {
      this.inputHelperTextVisible = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: How does initializing with `null` help you? why don't you initialize it as empty string? Anyway, just add a check for null. `if (this.expenses === null || this.expenses.toString() === '')...`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried removing the toString?

```
if (this.expenses == null) {
  this.inputHelperTextVisible = false;
} else {
  this.inputHelperTextVisible = true;
}
```

If you use == rather than === expenses will be checked if it is undefined in addition to checking if it it null.

Answer (score 0):

You needn't set to null

```
export class ExpensesLogComponent implements OnInit {
  inputHelperTextVisible = false;
  expenses: number;
```

and check null or empty

```
if (!this.expenses || this.expenses.toString() == '') { }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have several options to avoid a mistake.
But I propose the one of nested loops to avoid any problems typescript.

```
    // it will work
    if(this.expenses != null) {
       if (this.expenses.toString() === '') {
          this.inputHelperTextVisible = false;
        } else {
          this.inputHelperTextVisible = true;
       }
    } else{
      this.inputHelperTextVisible = false;
    }
```